# How do I manually update pubspec.yaml?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get dependencies for my pubspec yaml file after I made changes. However, first, I can't even see my IOS Emulator anymore (it seems to have disappeared). I am using MacOS.

Could you please tell me how to update pubspec yaml manually on Android Studio, normally there is a ribbon which shows, but after I made changes, no ribbon has showed up. Also, if you know how to make my IOS emulator (Xcode simulator) show up again, that would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Check the documentation https://docs.flutter.dev/reference/flutter-cli, which shows you how to get dependencies from command line

Answer (score 0):

Go to menu bar > Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Simulator